# Is there a better way to create a Django REST Web Service?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Python Django - further to my question.

I create a REST Web Service but I'm totaly unhappy with my code, but i can not find ab better solution.  Is it really  necessary to create new classes for each new URL part? If not, how can I find a better way for this issue?

**urls.py**

urlpatterns

```
 = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^movement/$', views.MovementDirection.as_view()),
    url(r'^movement/on/$', views.On.as_view()),
    url(r'^movement/off/$', views.Off.as_view()),
    url(r'^movement/stop/$', views.Stop.as_view()),
    url(r'^movement/forward/$', views.Forward.as_view()),
    url(r'^movement/backwards/$', views.Backward.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**views.py**

```
...
#movement/forward
class Forward(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        print("FORWARD")
        # engine control
        return Response("Forward")

#movement/backwards
class Backward(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        print("BACKWARD")
        # engine control
        return Response("Backward")
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you do not have to create a new class for a new url, what you need is a new action in your viewset.

```
url(r'^movements/$', views.MovementDirection.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class MovementDirection(ModelViewSet): # please notice the class
    @list_route
    def register(self, request):
        # you can make it on a whole endpoint
        # or on a single instance by using @detail_route
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410432/django-rest-framework-using-detail-route-and-detail-list) for more info on @detail_route vs @list_route

Then you can call it by a request to `movements/register`

Comment: Thank you for your very fast reply, An error occurse and turns me to the following question: I get an error to change the `urls.py` entry to ` url(r'^movements/', views.MovementDirection.as_view({'get': 'on'})),` and remove annotation.   The annotaiton error was `NameError: name 'list_route' is not defined`. And the other error was `TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Comment: Annotation Error --> checked ;) --> import was missing

Comment: You have to import a `list_route` from `rest_framework.decorators`.
I am not sure if that works on a `ViewSet`, maybe I misled you with my answer.

Comment: well.. to complete this issue there are my steps.  `url(r'^movements/on/$', views.MovementDirection.as_view({'get':'on'})),
    url(r'^movements/off/$', views.MovementDirection.as_view({'get':'off'})),` I define the URL for each subURL, and I add the method to each annotation  `@detail_route(methods=['get'])` in the `views.py` file